# std::shared_ptr null check results in compilation fatal error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shared-ptr

I want to check if a certain shared_ptr is null.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<program> ProgramPtr;

ProgramPtr progPtr =output.getProgram(num);
if (!progPtr)
    return false;
```

When I'm building the project I get an error:

" fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler."

This happens only when I build in Release configuration and not in Debug configuration .

In addition, the following null check don't create any problem in build

```
int index = progPtr? progPtr->getIndex() : -1;
```

Any idea why it happens?

Compiler version Visual studio c++ 14.1

Comment: Add compiler and exact version of it used please.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/178011/memory1390-fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has.html ?

Comment: added Compiler version: Visual studio c++ 14.1

Comment: It happens because there is a bug ("internal error") in the compiler. The usual way to work around those is to change the code into something different, but logically equivalent, through trial and error. Or upgrade the compiler.

Comment: An internal compiler error is always a result of a bug in the compiler and not any problem with your code. (This doesn't automatically mean that your code is free of problems of course).

Comment: can it be reason that you use a static instance of shared_ptr? In that case it contains a reference, ref count never zero and it is never a null. I saw older versions of MS compiler freak out if it's used to be captured in lambda expressions, may be it's a similar issue. Can't tell without seeing\trying out a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to the shared_ptr. The line that causes the error was :

```
 return false;
```

The problem was that the "return false" was inside a thread loop

```
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nThreads) private(locPt)
```

It seems that it's not possible to return inside a thread.